# Minio URL - Credentials

Tags: go, amazon-s3, url, minio

We are using minio for storage file releases.

We are using the go cdk library to convert s3 to http.

The problem is, when I try to execute a release I'm having this issue:** NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.**
This is the URL we are using: "s3://integration-test-bucket?endpoint=minio.9001&region=us-west-2" . It's any way to pass credentials to the URL itself? In this case, It will not be sensitive data as we are running it locally.
Note: I'm using docker compose yml and default environment for minio_access_key and minio_secret_key. (minioadmin & minioadmin).

I tried several types of query parameters inside URL to pass credentials. The goal is to not touch go CDK library itself, but pass credentials through URL or pass dummy credentials/avoid credentials checking.

Comment: What do you mean by "or pass dummy credentials"?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide following environment variables to the service/container that tries to connect to minio:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${MINIO_USER}
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${MINIO_PASSWORD}
AWS_REGION=${MINIO_REGION_NAME}
```

The library should pick them up during container startup and use when executing requests.

Comment: Hey! Thank you. This worked for me... But, we actually don't want to hardcode the aws access keys into our docker compose file. Do you have any idea if we can disable authentication for minio?

Comment: @miguelcaldeira On minio's side probably, but your lib won't allow not having credentials. You can use `.env` file placing it near your docker-compose file and specify those values there. You can add it to .gitignore if you want.